# How to extract JSON Data? I have a different pattern

Tags: json, flutter

The JSON Data I use is given below

{"0":{"id":"1","name":"test"},
"1":{"id":"2"},"name":"test123"}}

How do I extract these data and use it in my Flutter program?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and specifically where you're having an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link may help

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-convert/json-constant.html

e.g.

```
var encoded = json.encode([1, 2, { "a": null }]);
var decoded = json.decode('["foo", { "bar": 499 }]');
```